# Copying Arrays The Right Way

Tags: java, arrays

I came across 2 examples from my notes which is about copying arrays.

The first example given below, stated that it is not the way to copy an array. But, when i tried to run the code, it managed to copy all the values from array1 to array2.

```
    int []array1={2,4,6,8,10};
    int []array2=array1;
    for(int x:array2){
        System.out.println(x);
    }
```

The second example given, was saying the right way to copy an array.

```
int[] firstArray = {5, 10, 15, 20, 25 };
int[] secondArray = new int[5];
for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++)
  secondArray[i] = firstArray[i];
```

My question is, are these 2 examples appropriate to be applied in coding or Example 2 is preferred. If you were my lecturer, I were to apply Example 1.. I will be given less mark compared to Example 2 method or just the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first example doesn't copy anything. It assigns a reference of the original array to a new variable (`array2`), so both variables (`array1` and `array2`) refer to the same array object.

The second example actually creates a second array and copies the contents of the original array to it.

There are other easier ways of copying arrays. You can use `Arrays.copyOf` or `System.arraycopy` instead of explicitly copying the elements of the array via a for loop.

```
int[] secondArray = Arrays.copyOf (firstArray, firstArray.length);
```

or

```
int[] secondArray = new int[firstArray.length];
System.arraycopy(firstArray, 0, secondArray, 0, firstArray.length);
```

Answer (score 4):

Perfect way to copy elements is

```
System.arraycopy(array1,0, array2, 0, array1.length);
```

That above code is replacement for you second example which avoids a for loop.

And where in your first example, you are just referring the first array. So what ever changes happened to the first array can be seen from second array.

> My question is, are these 2 examples appropriate to be applied in coding or Example 2 is preferred.

See again, they are not doing the something to compare. First one pointing to array reference and second snippet of code referencing elements it it. So you just can't compare them.

And there are other ways to copy array elements as well just like others mentioned and I prefer `System.arraycopy` because

1)`Arrays.copyOf` creates another array object internally and returns it where as System.arraycopy uses the passed array.

2) Clone is the too slow. Never use it unless you have no other choice. 
There are few reasons I'm avoid clone. Here is 
[`Josh Bloch analysis on clone vs copy constructor`](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html) (*when you clone individual elements*).

Comment: OK, but now there are other concerns. Why are you saying that `clone` is too slow?

Comment: Not for array copying. The general advice is never to implement `Cloneable` or to override `clone`, but for array copying it's a different matter, because it is natively implemented and properly cast. You can see [this interview with Joshua Bloch](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html) (second paragraph from the end).

Comment: Funny, you have a link to the same interview in your answer where it says the exact opposite of what you claim. :-)

Comment: @RealSkeptic LOL. I want to bang my head. I mean in `for` loop. Just do a downvote, that my answer become neutral :P

Answer (score 3):

To demonstrate the problem with the first method, try this:

```
int[] array1 = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10};
int[] array2 = array1;
array1[0] = 0;
System.out.println(array2[0]);
```

What do you think this will print?

> 0

It will print 0, because `array2` now points to `array1`:
both variables now refer to the same object,
so modifying the content of any one of these will appear to modify both.

So your first method is NOT called copying an array.
It's a simple assignment, from one variable to another,
in this case assigning the value of `array1` to `array2`,
so that both variables point to the same thing.

As for your second method,
here's a much simpler way to accomplish the same thing:

```
int[] array2 = array1.clone();
```

Comment: Clone is the too slow. Never use it unless you have no other choice.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I looked around but it seems debatable. Do you have a link to an authoritative reference?

Comment: Sure. Here you go with Joshua's analysis : http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html

Comment: The article is about `clone` in general, only briefly mentions about arrays, and when it does it says the opposite of your suggestion: *"You should use clone to copy arrays, because that's generally the fastest way to do it."*

Comment: agreed with you. I'm reading many articles here and confused with that. It's just opposite as you said. My bad.

Comment: In any case, I never said it's the fastest way. At all. It's a simple, idiomatic way to copy an array (shallow), compared to what's in the OP. I honestly don't know the fastest way, and it might depend on a lot of things (JVM, version, platform, ...)

Comment: Exactly. I remember I saw a benchmark (`Not for array, that is for an individual object`) where the statics changed from JVM to JVM. Trying to find it, but no need I guess. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, you end up with only **one array** with two variables *referring* to it. Assignment only passes a reference to the array. So both `firstArray` and `secondArray` are pointing to the same array. It's not a copy. Try to set `firstArray[0] = 99` and print `secondArray` and you'll see it's the same array.

In the second example, it's an actual copy - you have created a new array and copied each value. Now, assigning `firstArray[0] = 99` won't change the array referred to by `secondArray` because it's a **copy**.

So the answer is: if you give the first way, you'll get lower marks.

In real use, there are better ways to copy arrays, using `System.arraycopy`, `Arrays.copyOf` or `firstArray.clone()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] secondArray = new int[5];
```

In the second example, you are creating an array of int using `new` operator and copying the elements to it manually using for loop. Whenever you use `new` operator in java, a new memory allocation happens (object creation).

Where as in the first, it is just reference assignment, both are pointing to same array. You can easily verify that by changing the content of one array see the same effect into the second array. This will not happen in the second array copying.

```
int []array2=array1;
```